# Font-Awesome Icons Not Showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, font-awesome, font-awesome-4

I installed the font-awesome Rails gem but the icons aren't showing. Instead, in Chrome, I get an empty box (shown below).

[image: screen shot 2013-11-22 at 12 09 45 pm]

I added `gem 'font-awesome-sass'` to my gemfile, ran `bundle`, and added `*= require font-awesome` to my application.css file.

I also tried adding

`<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">`

to the head, as described in the Getting Started section on the Font-Awesome website, but had the same result.

Has anyone else come across the same problem?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds familiar... I can't remember if I had the same issue but I seem to remember the following process fixed an update of font-awesome for me.

- Stop your server
- Clearing the tmp directory
- Restart the server

You can clear the tmp with rake:

```
bundle exec rake tmp:clear
```

Also, what does your markup look like when your trying to create the icon?

Comment: Thanks for asking me about the markup. I forgot to add the 'fa' class. Stupid me.

Comment: Clearing out the `tmp/` directory fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add :

`@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";`

to my application.scss file and then it worked for me. I also had the demon square box but this fixed it. Hope it helps someone.